# Postgres failed to create database for rails-composer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

I'm running the rails-composer script with

```
rails new myproject -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/compser.rb
```

And everything goes along smoothly until it asks me if I want to go ahead and drop the db in.  I say yes.  All drops fail, and all creations fail.

Everything else finished fine.  And testing the site brings up a beautiful error site with lots of details on how the database password wasn't accepted.  But of course it was never created...

How do I give the script permission to create the database without a password?  I've tried preempting creating the username as the app name in postgres.  I tried building the Rails project as the postgres user.

It should be a simple and straightforward solution since the rest is automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify something other than `SQLite` for the database?

From the README:

> Choose “SQLite” for the easiest setup. If you choose PostgreSQL or
>   MySQL, the databases must be installed and running before you run
>   Rails Composer.

Rails composer does not install and setup your database server for you. It assumes there's a properly named database already present before you run this if you're using PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: Yes I had set PostgreSQL.  So then I take that it needs to be manually converted over after the SQLite build.  I can manage that.